# Jquery Error in ie8 and ie9 with Wordpress theme. (Object doesnt support this property or method)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I recently launched a website for a client http://www.bridgechurch.us/ only to recieve complaints of it not displaying correctly on ie8 or ie9. I have confirmed this to be true. IE is pointing to this line of Javascript:

> jQuery(function () {
>
> jQuery(".scrollable").scrollable({circular: true}).navigator().autoscroll({interval: 7000});
>
> [...]

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with this line of code?

Thank you

> UPDATE - FIXED
>
> I figured out that there was a comment before the Doctype Declaration that forced IE into quirks mode.

Comment: `jQuery(".scrollable").scrollable({circular: true})` returns an object called `t`, not the original selector results.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of 404's on that page, mainly related to ie-specific css and border images, which is probably why the page doesn't look like it should.  Files like /images/internet_explorer/borderBottomRight.png and /wp-content/themes/Moses/styles/default.css aren't loading.

That being said, looking at [the scrollable documentation](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scrollable/index.html), there is no .navigator() function off of the return value of scrollable(); and I'm getting the same error in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Well, visually, the site doesn't appear to work well at all in IE9 (compared to Chrome). But just looking at the code that adds `scrollable()` to jQuery, you can see that that function doesn't always return the original element. In your code, if you split the call into two, you might be ok:

```
jQuery(".scrollable").scrollable({circular: true});
jQuery(".scrollable").navigator().autoscroll({interval: 7000});
```

I blame the plug-in on this one: functions that extend jQuery are *supposed* to always return the original elements found by the selector.

Comment: Your last comment about `data` and `attr` is incorrect, `data` can be used to other variables besides string, but `attr` is still a valid option. (I'm talking about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10691209/601179)) But he clearly did it the wrong way...